# join two collections on a custom condition

Tags: c#, linq, join, grouping

I have two collections, `IEnumerable<A> as` and `IEnumerable<B> bs`

I also have a predicate `Func<A, B, boolean> predicate`

I would like to join `as` and `bs` together to get something equivalent to an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<A, B>> joined` such that for each element `group` in `joined`, for each element `b` in `group`, `predicate(group.key, b)` holds.

To get such a grouping, there usually is the `GroupBy` extension method, but that cant operate based on a custom predicate.

I considered two approaches, one just building a collection with nested loops, the other doing the same with `Aggregate`. Both look really ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

In this particular case, for each element `b` in `bs` there is exactly one `A` in `as` for which the predicate holds, and I don't mind relying on that property if that makes for a nicer solution.

As far as I can see, in the general case it can't make for a better asymptotic runtime complexity than `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of `as` and `m` is the length of `bs`. I'm OK with that.

Comment: Can you better explain how the group by predicate works?

Comment: @GiladGreen for the scope of this question, just assume that I get it passed through from somewhere, and I know nothing about it.

Comment: What I mean is what is the signature of that predicate? Func<A,B,object> ?

Comment: @GiladGreen It's `Func<A, B, boolean> predicate`

Comment: This really sounds like nested loops, i.e. something like `As.Select(a => new { Key = a, Elements = Bs.Where(b => predicate(a, b)) });`, leading to O(N * M) time complexity. I don't see how that could be optimized based just on a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have

```
IEnumerable<A> aEnumerable;
IEnumerable<B> bEnumerable;
```

and the following restriction:

> In this particular case, for each element b in bs there is exactly one A in as for which the predicate holds

You may do the following:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<A, B>> grouping = bEnumerable
    .GroupBy(b => aEnumerable.Single(a => func(a, b)));
```

Another option which comes to mind and looks more convenient is a simple dictionary:

```
IEnumerable<A> aEnumerable;
IEnumerable<B> bEnumerable;

Dictionary<A, B[]> dict = aEnumerable
    .ToDictionary(a => a, 
                  a => bEnumerable.Where(b => func(a, b)).ToArray());
```

For every key A in this dictionary there will be those items which hold this predicate.